# Can detect only the first host service SQLTABLEDEPENDENCY

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I have a console app that have two services declared in the `App.config` but in other Project, only the first host service can be detected.
 The error is:

> HTTP 405:Method Not Allowed

```
<service name="ServicioBroker.Servicio.tabla_contenedor">
    <endpoint address="get" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="ServicioBroker.Cambios.IContenedor">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ServicioTablaContenedor/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>

  <service name="ServicioBroker.Servicio.buques">
    <endpoint address="get" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="ServicioBroker.Cambios.IBuques">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ServicioTablaBuques/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to declare the hosted service

here I attach the Project 
https://github.com/jafetrd/BDatos_API/tree/master/ServicioBroker

I start the services inside the service1 class, with the following code:

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(tabla_contenedor)); 
host.Open(); 
Console.WriteLine($"Servicio 1 iniciado en {host.Description.Endpoints[0].Address}");

while (!(host.State == CommunicationState.Opened)) { } 
var host2 = new ServiceHost(typeof(buques)); 
host2.Open(); 
Console.WriteLine($"Servicio 2 iniciado en {host2.Description.Endpoints[0].Address}");
```

I would like to know how to detect the SECOND service hosted, I try the code only with the SECOND one, and my client application can't detect it.

Comment: You want to host them in order or just want to know if a service is hosted?

Comment: The service is hosted, but when I try to use them as a connected service only the first can be detected in the client application, but the SECOND one can be detected, and both of them are almost the same